# Compute Stats Issue on Impala 1.2.4

Tags: impala

We are facing issues with Impala compute stats on a specific table. Issue details are listed below:

**Issue**

At times Impala's compute stats statement takes too much time to complete or just fails on a specific table

**Table Details**

Size: 45 GB Parquet with Snappy compression

No of Records : 4.1 billion

Partition : Partitioned on two columns.

**Observations Made**

- We observe different behavior from impala every time we run compute stats on this particular table. Some time it finishes in 8-10 minutes, while at other times it gets stuck and keeps running for 2 hrs before throwing an exception.
- On occasions when the compute stats works successfully in Impala, the backend impala query for stats collection contains NDV for each column in the table. However on all other occasions, the backend query calculates only count(*) for the partitioned columns. (for more details find attached screenshot)
- Digging into the impalad errors, I see some nodes having issues talking to ip-xxx-xxx-x-xxx at the same time. However, apart from these nodes, others are working fine.
  ./i-2f58f021/apps/impalad.ip-xxx-xxx-x-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal.hadoop.log.INFO.20150128-053250.3948.gz:I0128 06:11:26.943601 7420 status.cc:44] Couldn't open transport for ip-xxx-xxx-x-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal:22000(connect() failed: Connection timed out)

**Resolution Options Tried**

set NUM_SCANNER_THREAD=2 and then run the compute stats query. Post that we reset the NUM_SCANNER_THREAD. This has not helped.

**Cluster Size**

1 r3.2xlarge namenode | 39 r3.2xlarge datanode on AWS

**Questions**

1. What goes in the background behind impala compute stats logic?
2. Are there more session level properties that can be used to optimize the compute stats statements?
3. Can connection timed out Impalad communication between nodes via port 22000 be a reason for the compute stats failure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use impala web ui , or impala log to see what query gets fired while you fire compute stats

Yes you can change default timeout in imapla config .